# What are VDT's?

Tags: the-matrix

VDTs are mentioned a couple of times in The Matrix Revolutions, both times in connection with self-harming, both times in connection with Bane:

> **Maggie:** The Captain has some questions for him. He better have some good answers. You see these cuts? I think they're self-inflicted.
>   **Trinity** : Why?
>   **Maggie:** VDTs, maybe. I don't know. But like I said, the answer had better be good.

So, **what are VDTs?**

---

Oh, and for the record, if you're planning to tell me they're [(Virtual) Delirium Tremens](http://annex.wikia.com/wiki/Virtual_delirium_tremens), you need to back it up with **actual proof**, not web-speculation :-)

Comment: Some versions of the script have this line transcribed as "DDTs" rather than "VDTs". Do we know which one is correct?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor If true, that might seem to provide some support for the Virtual Delirium Tremens theory, since DDTs could be *Digital* Delirium Tremens.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor - Can you post a link to these scripts?

Comment: Here's [one](http://thematrixtruth.remoteviewinglight.com/html/revolutions-transcript-1.html) and [another](http://www.code-matrix.net/3-23.htm). I'm not saying that these are official scripts or official transcriptions - just that I haven't seen an official script, and the unofficial transcriptions vary.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor -Ah, ok. These seem to be a fan-transcriptions of the movie.

Comment: Yeah that's what I suspected. It would improve the question if you added a link the the official script.

Comment: There's a scanned copy of the shooting script [here](https://anonfiles.com/file/525f3e9330fc4c974802ac629d8f6257) to use as a reference. I have no reason to doubt that it's not authentic.

Comment: @Richard Do you have a reason to believe it is not Virtual Delirium Tremens our are you just looking for some hardcore digging?

Comment: @Skooba - As I've said, just because some random internet person took a wild guess that that's what it stands for, why should I take their word? Note that there are at least **three** other uses of that acronym in my medical dictionary; Vascular Dilatation and Tortuosity / Visual Disturbance and Tremors / Ventricular Diastolic Thresholds.

Comment: @Valorum My internet security reports unwanted software on that site.

Comment: @Gandalf - Your security is overly protective of you. Live a little.

Comment: @Valorum Can't afford to. I make my living off this machine.

Comment: @Gandalf - If your security is dialled up so high that a pdf pops a flag then I can't help you.

Comment: I fear that unless someone here knows the very secretive Wachowski sisters, this question is probably unanswerable.

Comment: @Jonah - You'd be surprised at what is and isn't unanswerable.

Comment: Best source I could find. While not concrete, seems pretty accurate. http://annex.wikia.com/wiki/Virtual_delirium_tremens

Comment: @Xiokraze - As I've [pointed out above](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126300/what-are-vdts?noredirect=1#comment316267_126300), the problem with wikis is that they're fan-written. There's no ***evidence*** that that's what it means other than the say-so of whichever fan wrote this. The fact that they copy/pasted large chunks of this article from wikipedia without citation certainly doesn't help me think that they're reliable.

Comment: Violent dissociative trance?  Violent dissociative trauma?

Comment: I so wish that I could sit with the Wachowski brothers to discuss the trilogy and the research they did for the movie :)

Comment: @ABcDexter - The Wachowskis (no longer [brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wachowskis), BTW) are notoriously secretive. The "making of" documentary that came with the DVDs is about 90% others and only about 10% them, and even then they're mostly discussion storyboarding, lighting and CGI rather than anything about the film's story.

Comment: Ohh, is that so. I just watched the 'The Matrix Revolutions' 20+th time, and found a new thing to question about. I'll be posting a question right now, I think :) also, hope that it's not been asked yet.

Comment: Previous anon link to the script doesn't seem to work anymore. Here's another one: https://www.screenwritersnetwork.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/The-Matrix-Revolutions-Script.pdf

Comment: I wonder if there's _any_ chain of words that were pronounced by Morpheus that could potentially be related. I'm thinking, like, when they retrieved Neo in the real world or something, although I highly doubt it.

Comment: Only interesting thing I found was already mentioned on the wikia. For some unexplained reasons, they translated it in German into plain _Delirium vielleicht_: "Im Delirium vielleicht. Keine Ahnung. Aber wie ich schon sagte, hoffentlich hat er eine gute Erklärung."

Comment: @Clockwork - *"Delirious maybe. No idea. But like I said, hopefully he has a good explanation"* - That doesn't sound like a *direct* translation of the English script, but it's an interesting find.

Comment: @Clockwork - In Italian it was translated as *"- Perché?
- Delirium Tremens. Non lo so."*

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried to check the French transcript (I forgot to mention it but that was a German transcript). The French one says: "Delirium tremens virtuel peut-être. Il a intérêt à avoir des réponses satisfaisantes."; then further below when the other guy asks if he was tested: "Il a eu un dépistage de delirium virtuel?". Also, same question in German: "Wurde er auf Virtuelles Delirium getestet?"

Comment: The Hungarian is even closer to the mark - *Miért? Virtuális delirium tremens, vagy ilyesmi.*. If you want to write these up into an answer, I'd happily accept that. An official dubbing is definitely something that's agreed with the studio

Comment: Nah, I'm fine if you write the answer. I merely checked whether or not the wikia information was relevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Matrix Fandom](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/VDTs) mentioned in another answer highlighted the fact that the German translation used a full word instead of an abbreviation.

Upon checking a [downloadable German subtitles](https://www.opensubtitles.com/en/subtitles/matrix-revolutions-2003-remastered-hd-bluray-x265/subfiles/4739892/transcript) for the movie, I found the dialogue was translated as such:

> **Maggie:** Der Captain hat ein paar Fragen an ihn. Wär besser, wenn er gute Antworten hätte. Sehen Sie diese Schnittwunden? Die hat er sich wohl selbst zugefügt.
>
> **Trinity:** Wieso?
>
> **Maggie:** Im **Delirium** vielleicht. Keine Ahnung. Aber wie ich schon sagte, hoffentlich hat er eine gute Erklärung.

*"Im Delirium"* translates into *"delirious"* according to [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/Im%20Delirium). That's not much, but it's a first lead.

Out of curiosity, I decided to check for transcripts/subtitles in other languages to see if they translated differently. So I found [downloadable French subtitles](https://www.opensubtitles.org/fr/subtitles/3591372/the-matrix-revolutions-fr), for which the conversation was translated this way:

> **Maggie:** Le capitaine a des questions à lui poser. Ses réponses devront le satisfaire. Ces entailles. Il les a faites.
>
> **Trinity:** Pourquoi ?
>
> **Maggie:** **Delirium tremens virtuel** peut-être. Il a intérêt à avoir des réponses satisfaisantes.

Which is literally ***Virtual Delirium Tremens***, save for the world *"virtuel"* which you probably guessed means *"virtual"* in French.

I didn't check whether or not the translations were validated as semantically accurate with the original version. But seeing as the German and French versions were both released with close meaning for that translation, VDT could have been intended to mean Virtual Delirium Tremens.

Comment: An excellent answer. The official dubbing would have been approved by the studio and the fact that it's the same in multiple versions (including the Hungarian, where it was "*Miért? Virtuális delirium tremens, vagy ilyesmi*") would strongly indicate that this was sent out with the dubbing notes.

Comment: @Valorum I just watched the actual French version to make sure the French subtitles were accurate, and they're a bit off but still more or less coherent. But they merely say "delirium, probably". Do you think I should update the answer?

Comment: Maybe replace it with something from another language version? The Hungarian version is in my comment above

Comment: @Valorum I just rechecked, and it seems the subtitles I had found were those included in the DVD (so it's official; even if it's off compared to the spoken lines, I'd like to say that it's always the case with translated movies). I guess I'll leave the answer as is to avoid bumping it.

Answer (score 0):

**Virtual Disease Transmissions**

According to *matrix.fandom.com*, the wiki dedicated to The Matrix franchise, VDTs was a medical condition in the Real World that was speculated to result from an infection of the mind (through hacking or other means) while within the Matrix. The acronym presumably stands for Virtual Disease Transmissions.

Among other interpretations (including Virtual Delirium Tremens, which indicates that the condition was caused by withdrawal from the Matrix, rather than alcohol, though there is no proof of this) the aforementioned explanation (Virtual Disease Transmissions) is more plausible given that there's no known way of testing for a hangover or withdrawal other than observation, but, there are ways to test for viruses and hacks which - combined with the similarity to the term "STD" (Sexually Transmitted Disease) makes the term 'Virtual Disease Transmission"  more reasonable.

A 'Virtual Disease Transmission" suggests that Mr. Smith's mind hack of Bane would be equivalent to a zero-day virus that evaded detection on egress from the Matrix.

Let us remember that Smith has incarnated Bane. Smith absorbed him and took his form. This Bane/Smith man -who says "Why would I cut myself, why would I give myself, self-inflicted wounds, unless I am not me, and if I am not me, who am I?"- is struggling with his 'two minds' which indicates that Mr. Smith was a program that managed to elude tracing as it took over Bane's mind with the excess neural activity - quite likely in the same way a zero day virus eludes detection. This matches the Virtual Disease Transmissions term.

https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/VDTs

Comment: @JMERICKS - I specifically asked for an evidence-based answer and said "***don't guess and don't just quote the wiki***" which is precisely what this answer does.