# What happened to Zathras when Babylon-4 disappeared back in time?

Tags: babylon-5, character-development, space-station

This is similar to [one of my other questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155116/what-happened-to-babylon-4-after-the-war-between-shadows-and-minbari-ended-a-tho), but instead of asking about the station, I am asking about a character who was on the station.

When Babylon-4 was nearing the final stages of construction, an unknown creature appeared on it. The station became unstuck in time and disappeared along with the creature.

[image]

We later discovered that the creature was Zathras, one of the caretakers of the Great Machine.

[image]

**What happened to him after the station took him back in time by a thousand years?**

I know what happened to his co-traveler, but not to him.

I will accept answers from canon sources along with writings, interviews, and comments by the producers or scriptwriters.

Comment: Whatever happened to him, I think we can assume he *passive-aggressively complained about it for the remainder of his miserable existence*.

Comment: Placing *specific restrictions* on what you'll accept as an answer is probably the wrong way to go about it. If I found an answer in a source that wasn't on that list, I might think twice about posting it.

Comment: @Radhil - I was just about to post some panels from that comic as an answer. But if you want to do the honours...

Comment: @Valorum I was not aware of the comic, *In Valen's Name*. I can modify my request to include canon sources and not just certain types of sources.

Comment: Personally, I'd just remove the sentence entirely. The implication of *every* question on the site is that higher level sources trump lower level ones and unless you want to exclude one kind of source entirely (for example, [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126300/what-are-vdts)) I'd tend to trust the audience to police themselves.

Comment: He had a very sad death. At least there was symmetry.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the (canon) comic [*In Valen's Name*](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/comic/012.html), Zathras remained a loyal and true companion to Sinclair throughout the Minbari-Shadow War, acting as liaison between the Minbari and Entil'Zha as well as helping with repairs to the station, repairs to damaged Minbari ships and generally assisting the war effort.

[image]

He also served as Sinclair's confidante and ultimately prevented him from stopping the Earth-Minbari War (by showing him the cyclical nature of time and that his actions would ultimately result in his own existence being negated and the loss of the Shadow War/s).

[image]

It's not stated what his fate was, although I think we can assume he grumbled about it until the very end.

Comment: "Ah Zathras. He was always the quiet one." No wonder we never heard from him after this.